# Function $f(n)\neq g(n)$ and $f(n+1)=g(n+1)$

Tags: functions, linear-transformations

Are they any functions such that the following is true.

$$
f(n)\neq g(n)\text{ and }f(n+1)=g(n+1)
$$

When I was reading on linear operators, this popped up. Let $V$ be the set of all functions $F:\mathbb{N}→\mathbb{R}$ such that $lim_{(n→\infty)}f(n)$ exists. Then the it defined $T:V→V$ as $(Tf)(n)=f(n+1)$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now I was thinking if the linear operator was injective.

Comment: Is $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? Also you want this to hold for a specific value of $n$?

Comment: $f:\mathbb{N} → \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{N} → \mathbb{R}$, any value of $n$ would do

Comment: The two conditions cannot hold for *all* $n$, but they can hold for infinitely many $n$, such as $n$ even (and $n+1$ odd).

Comment: For what $n$ do you want this to be true?  If it is all $n$ it is contradictory as you can substitute $n+1$ in the left equation

Comment: When I was reading on linear operators, this popped up. Let $V$ be the set of all functions $F:\mathbb{N}→\mathbb{R}$ such that $lim_{(n→\infty)}f(n)$ exists. Then the it defined $T:V→V$ as $(Tf)(n)=f(n+1)$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now I was thinking if the linear operator was injective.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$. Then $f(0) = g(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1 \neq 0 = g(1)$.

**EDIT:** Your second question about the linear operator is a bit  different from the first one. Let $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $Tf = 0$. Then $f(n+1) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. This implies that $f(n) = 0$ for all $n \geq 2$. However, $f(1)$ can be anything so the operator is not injective.

Comment: I see, thank you for that. I'm still just new to site and I don't get why this got so many downvotes. Also, proving subjectivity, we can say that $f(n-1) \in V$ thus $Tf(n-1) = f(n) \in V$, which is a mapping from $V$ to $V$. Does that sound right?

Comment: It's almost right. If $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ then set $g(n) = f(n-1)$ for $n > 1$ and $g(1) = 0$ (or whatever you like) and then $Tg = f$ so $T$ is surjective. If you found my answer useful then you can click on the gray tick on the left to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you again, I really appreciate it!